# Looping in Javascript for SVG objects

Tags: javascript, loops

I had written a program for 14 numbers of different SVG objects.And I want to write a single loop program for each and every SVG object to get its point of center . I preferred using loop statement in my code with Javascript.

I had tried using JavaScript but it's not being looped repeatedly.

JavaScript code goes here;

```
    var i=1;
    while(i<15){
      gear = document.getElementById("gear"+i);
      let aa = gear.getBBox()
      let a = {};
      a.x = aa.x + aa.width/2;
      a.y = aa.y + aa.height/2;
      gear.setAttribute("style",`transform-origin:${a.x}px ${a.y}px` );
      i++;
    }
```

I had given unique id for each SVG object as (gear1, gear2, gear3,.....,gear14).

The final result must be looping the code for each and every SVG objects.

Comment: How is your loop called? Can you show a reproducable example? I would think you just use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame to schedule the next draw cycle.

Comment: The better way is to give same class to all elements. Instead of ids like `gear1,gear2...` and then get it using `querySelectorAll()` and loop using `forEach`

Comment: D you have more information or errors? If I copy paste your code and add a bunch of `<svg>` elements with those IDs, I get 14 iterations out of the loop, as expected. The x and y don't work for me, but the loop does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `querySelectorAll()` for that. You can select all gears which ids start with "gear". And I wouldn't use `a` or `aa` as a variable name. It's just confusing.

```
let gears = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='gear']"); // get all gears

// Now convert "gears" into an array and loop it
Array.from(gears).forEach(function(gear){
    let bbox = gear.getBBox();
    let styles = {};
    styles.x = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
    styles.y = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;

    gear.setAttribute("style", `transform-origin:${styles.x}px ${styles.y}px`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var i=1;
let gear =[]
    while(i<3){
      gear[i] = document.getElementById("gear"+i);
    //  alert(gear[i])
      let aa = gear[i].getBBox();
      let a = {};
      a.x = aa.x + aa.width/2;
      a.y = aa.y + aa.height/2;
      gear[i].setAttribute("style",`transform-origin:${a.x}px ${a.y}px` );
      i++;
    }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
    <g id="gear1"> 
        <text x="5" y="16" transform="scale(2, 2)">Hello World!</text> 
        <text x="8" y="32" transform="translate(0 20) scale(1.25 1)">Hello World Again!</text> 
    </g> 
    <g id="gear2"> 
        <text x="5" y="16" transform="scale(5, 8)">Hello World2!</text> 
        <text x="8" y="32" transform="translate(0 20) scale(1.25 1)">Hello World Again!</text> 
    </g> 
    <g id="gear3"> 
        <text x="5" y="16" transform="scale(3, 5)">Hello World3!</text> 
        <text x="8" y="32" transform="translate(0 20) scale(1.25 1)">Hello World Again!</text> 
    </g> 
  
</svg>
```